# Cannot apply operator && to operands of type String and String()

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having cannot apply operator && to operands of type String and String() at the below code. Anyone knows what's the cause for this issue?

```
If IsValidEmail(EmailAddress) Then
   EncodedData += "&data[]=" +
       + HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode( _
                  (Convert.ToString((Convert.ToString("{""email"":""") _
                  & EmailAddresses) + """,""name"":""") & Name) + """}")
End If
```

Comment: where you use `&&` in your snippet? `&&` is used for comparison not for concatination

Comment: There is no `&&` operator in VB. Do you mean `&` (string concatenation)? If so then likely one of the variables you are passing is an array of strings: based on naming `EmailAddresses` (as a plural) seems a likely candidate.

Comment: Suggestion: break the expression into multiple statements (with temporary variables): this will make understanding much easier.

Comment: I'm just struggling to understand the thinking behind parts like `Convert.ToString("{""email"":""")` - what do you think this is being converted *from*?

Comment: If you have a new question, you ought to post it *as* a new question, not completely change your current question so that existing comments/answers don't make any sense. If it's more of a variant, then yes, [tag:edit] your question, but again be aware of existing responses and don't invalidate them.

Answer (score 2):

If `EmailAddresses` is an array, you have to decide how to combine the potentially multiple values in there.

Maybe, something like:

```
String.Join(";",EmailAddresses)
```

So that the addresses are `;` separated? Or maybe, since this is inside an `If` block that checks a different, but probably related variable, you intended this reference to be `EmailAddress`, not `EmailAddresses`.

---

So, either:

```
EncodedData += "&data[]=" _
       & HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode("{""email"":""" _
                  & String.Join(";",EmailAddresses) & """,""name"":""" _
                  & Name & """}")
```

or:

```
EncodedData += "&data[]=" _
       & HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode("{""email"":""" _
                  & EmailAddress & """,""name"":""" _
                  & Name & """}")
```

Where I've also removed the pointless conversions of strings into (better?) strings and the mixing of string concatenation operators.